# Method to delete certain level of binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have class `SimpleTree` just basic binary tree:

```
public class SimpleTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
protected class TreeItem {
    public T value;
    public TreeItem left;
    public TreeItem right;

    public TreeItem(T value, TreeItem left, TreeItem right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public TreeItem(T value) {
        this(value, null, null);
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public TreeItem getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public TreeItem getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

protected TreeItem item = null;
protected int size = 0; // number of elements
```

And the problem is to write method:

```
 public void delete(TreeItem item, int level) {
...
}
```

Where `level` is the level of the elements in some tree (root level == 0). For example `level == 1`:

```
Before:
            8 ----- 0 level root
           / \
          /   \  (size == 6)
         /     \
        5       10 ----- 1 level
       / \       \
      2   6      11 ----- 2 level and etc.

After:
                8 ----- 0 level
               / \
              /   \   (size == 3)
             /     \
            /       \ 
           /         \
          2           11 ----- 1 level
```

Only LEFT leaf of DELETED elements is saved, if we dont have such -> save the right.

Comment: And what is your question? What errro do you get? Where does the actual output not match your expectations?

Comment: i dont have an error, the question is how to write such method delete

Comment: Where are you stuck with the implementation? Are there any edge cases that are not handled correctly? How would you solve it and why doesn't it work? Stack Overflow is not a "please write code for me" platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tree seems to be a recursive data structure.

Suppose you want to delete Level N, then traverse down recursively to `N- 1`
[image: Step 1]
Check at Level N-1 for four cases:

1. it has a left and a right child (node 2)
2. it has only a left child (node 6)
3. it has only a right child (node 10)
4. no children (node 7)

When you try to delete Level N
[image]
You have to fixup the remaining nodes
[image]
That is why you start at Level N-1, because you need the parent of each node at level N for the fix-up phase.

The four cases above can easily be reduced to:

- If the left child of the left child exists, set the left child to the left child of the left child. (4.left = 4.left.left)
- else if the right child of the left child exists, set the left child to the right child of the left child. (4.left = 4.left.right)
- else NO-OP

For the right child e.g. node 4 it's exactly the same.

Actually, the fix-up is all you need. Afterwards, let the GC clean up for you and you are done.